# Remove duplicates keys and save only newest

Tags: java, list

What are the bests practices in Java with List ?
Here's my problem :

I've got actually 2 objects : a `DataPoint` object, and a `Collector` object.

Collector have a`List<DataPoint>` List attribute.
This DataPoint object listed is define by 3 values :
A type, a value, and a unit.

My goal is to write a Collector's method which is going to remove duplicated TYPE elements in my DataPoint list, and store only the last.
So that at the end of this method, my List can only get differents DataPoint different type. No 2.

What are the best way to do that ? I'm Java begginer !

Comment: Post your code and we'll comemt on it.

Comment: You should have a `Map<Type, DataPoint>` then.

Answer (score 0):

Implement proper `hashCode` and `equals` methods on `DataPoint` class
and use `java.util.Set` implementation to store only unique values from your list.

```
Set<DataPoint> set = new HashSet<DataPoint>;
set.addAll(list);
```

Comment: This would ensure you keep `DataPoint`s of a unique `Type`, but not necessarily the **last** one.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the list from its end, save the unique types (e.g., using a `Set`), and remove any point the has a type you already encountered. E.g. (assuming the data member is called `points`):

```
public void retainUniqueTypes() {
    Set<Type> types = new HashSet<>();
    while (iter.hasPrevious()) {
        DataPoint current = iter.previous();
        if (!types.add(current.getType())) {
            iter.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is. Change `List<DataPoint>` to `Set<DataPoint>`, why because `Set` will not have duplicates in it. 
Also ensure that you have proper implementation of `equals` and `hashcode` in `DataPoint`

Comment: To make this do what the OP expects you'd have to have a fnuky implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` that only takes the Type into account. Even so, this would ensure you keep DataPoints of a unique Type, but not necessarily the **last** one.